# Why does my cheese sauce solidify

Tags: sauce, cheese

I am using this recipie to make cheese sauce for my maize crackers.
http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/nacho-cheese-sauce/detail.aspx

However, my sauce starts solidifying as it cools down. I am using a slice of provola instead of american cheese. could that be a problem?

Next time I tried doubling the milk andadding a little more flour, it fared a little better, but suffered the same fate. I need it to stay liquid for at least 90 minutes after removing from heat

Comment: Okay this time I put it on a hot water bath. Wonder why didnt I think of it earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes substituting provolone makes the difference.  Since American is a processed cheese, when it melts it doesn't become stringy but just goop.  I imagine that the recipe is specifc to American, maybe something like cheddar would fair well too.  But something like provolone which is close to mozzarella will become cohesive with itself as it cools.

Comment: So can i make a nachos sauce with provolone?

Comment: You can but you will probably need to keep it hot.  Don't know if you'll be near one, but you could always throw it in a microwave to melt it again.

Comment: As far as the second part of the question, one suggestion would be to use a vessel that retains heat. Enameled cast iron is a traditional material for fondue pots, and it will hold heat for a while. Also check out some of the material on how to keep fondue from clumping: http://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/icooks/12-29-03.html

Comment: You'll need to process your provolone first. Melt it slowly, add liquid and emulsifier. I think there was a Food Lab article on that 2-3 months ago. The downside is that you'll get the taste of processed cheese. Such cheese sauces aren't meant to stay liquid without heat, so if you want the good taste of real cheese, you'll need to imitate a fondue in some way (either with a real fondue kit, or by placing a tea light under the pan).

Comment: Previously mentioned Food Lab article: http://aht.seriouseats.com/archives/2010/09/the-burger-lab-cheese-sauce-for-burgers-fries-and-chips.html

I used this method with cheddar and it was great.